# Regex: Find all those lines with a particular tag, that does not have a particular word in it

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I wanna find all those lines with a particular tag, that does not have a particular word in it. For example I wanna find this line:

`<p class="text_obisnuit"><span class="text_obisnuit2"> I love You </span>blah blah blah</p>`

and NOT those lines with tags that have `* Note:` in it, such as:

`<p class="text_obisnuit"><span class="text_obisnuit2"> * Note: </span> blah blah </p>`

So, the first example should be the output.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SU isn't a regex/script writing service.

Comment: hello Spikey. Indeed, I believe is not a writing service, bu maybe is a helping service for those that may have problems or do not not (so good) any programming language. I am not a programmer, but a web designer. I just know how to use regex, not knowing the formulas...

Comment: Do you want to match only or do a replacement?

Comment: hi, @Toto. Only match. But if you can, for the both variants. One variant will find the tags without `* Note:` and one will find those tags that has not `* Note:`. Just to be a complete answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<p class="text_obisnuit"><span class="text_obisnuit2">(?! \* Note:.*?</span>).*?</span>.*?</p>`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find Next</kbd>    *OR*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<p class="text_obisnuit">           # literally
<span class="text_obisnuit2">       # literally
(?! \* Note:.*?</span>)             # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't " * Note:" before closing "</span>"
.*?                                 # 0 or more any character, not greedy
</span>                             # end tag
.*?                                 # 0 or more any character, not greedy
</p>                                # end tag
```